# intersections of two functions, division by zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus

we're supposed to write a small program that calculates the intersections of $a(x-1)-by=0$ and $x^2+4y^2=3$. So far that's not such a big deal. I successfully calculate both points for all $b \ne 0$ (since $0=(4\frac{a^2}{b^2}+1)x^2-8\frac{a^2}{b^2}x+4\frac{a^2}{b^2}-3$).
But we're also supposed to give the intersection(s) for $b=0$, which is what I have no idea of.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: So, is this a question about mathematics, or about programming?

Comment: if $b=0$, then $a(x-1)=0$ from the 1st equation. Hence, $x=1$ no matter what $a$ is. Then, the 2nd eq becomes $4y^2=2$ from where you get $y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Mathematics ;)

Comment: @Cristian thanks... thats just too straight-forward ! @_@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, instead of comment I should've written it as my answer.

EDIT:

Suppose $a\neq 0$. If $b=0$, then $a(x−1)=0$ from the 1st equation. Hence, $x=1$ no matter what $a$ is. Then, the 2nd eq becomes $4y^2=2$ from where you get $y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$.

If $a=0$ and $b=0$, then $a(x-1)-by=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. In particular, it is true for $x=y$. Then, you get $y=x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$.

Comment: if a was 0 as well though, x could be basically anything.. right? how to handle that case?

Comment: @foaly. If $a$ and $b$ are both zero, your first equation could be satisfied by any $(x,y)$, so the intersection would then be any $(x,y)$ that satisfies $x^2+4y^2=3$.

Comment: @foaly I added an edit to my answer...

Comment: Why in particular for x=y when it's for any x,y satisfying that 2nd equation?

Comment: @foaly it is true for any $x$ and $y$, so it must be true for $y=x$.

Comment: gotta go to class now. coming back to this later :P

Comment: Why do you ignore the solutions with $\: a = 0 = b \:$ and $\: x\neq y \:$? $\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer I did not ignore those. I only gave a particular one such that $x=y$.

Comment: I don't see the use of that... Since there are intersections for any x,y that satisfy the 2nd equation, so I'd say $y=\frac{\sqrt{3-x^2}}{2}$?

Comment: @RickyDemer what do you think?